# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html for Chrome browser

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

I am trying to show image using encrypted code for **magento dashboard  graph image** and it is perfectly working in mozilla firefox but the same code is not working on google chrome and showing warning as **Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html**

Answer (score 1):

Just put the below line to `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff    
</IfModule>
```